# Laravel Form Request Validation | Парсинг файла и последующая валидация его содержимого

Tags: php, laravel, валидация

Имеется файл **.json** , его я хочу валидировать.

В контроллере:

```
public function import(ImportPost $request)
{
    ProcessImport::dispatch($request->validated());
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Сам файл ImportPost содержит в себе следующий код

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ImportPost extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'file' => 'required|file|max:10000',
        ];
    }
}
```

Собственно файл парсится с помощью:

```
json_decode(File::get($request->file('file')), true);
```

Так вот, как мне распарсить данный файл и валидировать в дальнейшем?

То есть, изначально это файл **file.json**, я хочу проверить его по весу, а его содержимое проверить по другим полям которые содержатся в нем.

Предполагаю возможность создать два валидатора и проверить сначала сам файл, а затем уже проверить его содержимое. Верный ли такой подход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант осуществления валидации, когда поля для проверки расположены не только в запросе, а формируются динамически, либо они должны присутствовать на постоянной основе.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ImportPostRequest extends FormRequest
{
  /**
   * Имя поля файла с данными для проверки.
   * @var string
   */
  const FILE_FIELD_NAME = 'file';

  /**
   * Подготовить данные для проверки.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  protected function prepareForValidation()
  {
    // Проверим сам файл, перед тем как
    // собрать необходимые данные для проверки.
    // Используем отдельный экземпляр валидатора,
    // созданный через функцию-помощник.
    validator($this->only(self::FILE_FIELD_NAME), [
        'file' => [
          'required',
          'file',
          'max:10000',
        ]
      ])
      ->validate();

    // `merge`- добавляем необходимые поля для проверки.
    $this->merge(json_decode(
      File::get($this->file(self::FILE_FIELD_NAME)
    ), true));
  }

  /**
   * Получите данные для проверки из запроса.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function validationData(): array
  {
    // `except` - получить массив полей, исключив ненужные.
    $input = $this->except([
      self::FILE_FIELD_NAME,
      '_token',
      '_method',
      'submit',

    ]);

    // `replace` - заменить поля на новые.
    // `merge` - добавить другие поля.
    return $this->replace($input)
      ->merge([
        // Еще можно легально добавить поля здесь.
      ])
      ->all();
  }

  /**
   * Получить правила проверки,
   * которые будут применены к запросу.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function rules(): array
  {
    return [
      'key' => [
        'required',
      ],

    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Примерно такой вариант решения я и хотел получить, спасибо за отличный пример!

Answer (score 1):

Laravel - **^6.2**

PHP - **^7.2**

---

Необходимо использовать хук **withValidator();** Что из себя представляет данный хук?

```
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $data = json_decode(File::get($this->file), true);
        $rules = [
            'key' => 'required'
        ];
        $validate = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($data, $rules);
        $validate->validate();
    });
}
```

Класс Validator подключается в начале файла:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
```

Что касается самого валидатора ниже, на 8ой строке, то там я указал все явно.

С помощью `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator`

В конце я вызвал метод validate(); чтобы исполнить правила.

Не совсем уверен что это правильно, но необходимой официальной документации я не нашел, поэтому следующий быдло-код имеет место быть.

---

Полный вид файла выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class ImportPost extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'file' => 'required|file|max:10000',
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator->after(function ($validator) {
            $data = json_decode(File::get($this->file), true);
            $rules = [
                'key' => 'required'
            ];
            $validate = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($data, $rules);
            $validate->validate();
        });
    }
}
```

---

Итог - мой вопрос решается с помощью метода **withValidator();**

Comment: А почему `быдло-код`, что вы хотели бы исправить, чтобы он таким не был или в чем сомнения?